# Formdata in expo app is being recieved in _parts but in object form when send from web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform

I am sending form to backend by using FormData and using multer on backend to recieve the data, it works fine on my web app but on doing the same axios call to submit data in react-native shows that data fields are being received on backend in following form

```
{ _parts: [ [ 'firstname', 'fahad' ], [ 'firstname', 'RAO' ] ] }
```

i am doing following call in my web app (which works there) and in my expo app

```
const testFOrmData = ()=>{
        
        var data = new FormData()
        data.append("firstname","fahad")
        data.append("firstnae","RAO")
        const adata  = {
            firsn:"rew"
        }
axios.post("http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/api/testform",data)
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
})
alert("SANS")
    }
```

How to receive it in object form such that i dont have to make changes in my existing code in backend as i have so many forms and i have submitted them using form data in my web app and have to do same in mobile app but i dont want to submit without FormData(by sending object in axios)

my backend

```
router.post("/testform",upload.none(),(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json({resp:req.body})
})
```

Comment: like this u can try it will send data in object instead of data in line of axios.post put this { 'firstname', 'fahad'  , 'firstname', 'RAO'}

Comment: yes I also mentioned that i dont want to pass it like that as I am uploading images too with FormData

Comment: so did u figure it out ???why _parts are coming im having the same issue..please let me know if u r done...

Comment: Actually no, not with this method and have spent a lot of time on it. I found another method if you have been facing the same scenario follow thishttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hX2wwONl4pI
They are using separate package to upload file along with other field i.e name,email